# Difference between font-size 190% and 200%

Tags: html, css

When I set the font-size: 200%

> [image]

When I set the font-size: 190%:

> [image]

I tested it on the firefox and I found it.

I don't know why "font-size: 200%" makes these differences...

```css
body {
  font-size: 190%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
input {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 5px 5px 12px 5px;
  font-size: 25px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px gray solid;
}
#wrapper {
  margin: 0, auto;
  width: 1000px;
}
lable {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}
.element-container {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="element-container">
    <lable for="email">Email</lable>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="input the email here">
  </div>
  <div class="element-container">
    <lable for="phone">Telephone</lable>
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="input the phone number here">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should state in the question itself, in text, what the difference is and what the problem with it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can give it a `padding-right` of 5% which will move the box away from the text.

```
lable {
 width: 100px;
 float: left;
 padding-right:5%;
}
```